# Does Xamarin have UI editor helps to drag and drop

Tags: xamarin

Is xamarin.form have UI editor that helps to drag and drop elements such buttons, labels and image
Instead of writing the codes

Comment: No... In xamarin you will have a markup language called Xaml that help's a lot but no drag and drop ui.

Answer (score 0):

**For Xamarin.Forms, the XAML Previewer used as UI editor before.**

But, it has been deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.8, and replaced by the XAML Hot Reload feature in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9.

For more details, you could check the MS docs of XAML Previewer.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?pivots=windows

**For Xamarin.Android, you could use the Designer as UI editor.**

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/designer-walkthrough?tabs=windows

**For Xamarin.iOS, the Designer has deprecated as well.**

Please check the MS docs about the iOS Designer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/?tabs=macos